# Adding arrays to an array using foreach

Tags: php

I'm trying to add multiple arrays to an array using foreach.

```
$data = array(
    array('name'=>'John','age'=>'19'), //loop 1
    array('name'=>'Bob','age'=>'32'),  //loop 2
    array('name'=>'Kate','age'=>'22'), //loop 3
                                       //more loops
);
```

How do I add more `array('name'=>'Kate','age'=>'22');` like arrays to `$data` array using foreach?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking -- you aren't using `foreach` at all in this code.  Also, your code won't run -- you have semicolons inside `array()`, which will break the parser.

Comment: how do you create your loop arrays?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like

```
$data[] = array('name'=>'Kate','age'=>'22');
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use [array_push](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php)..

```
array_push($data,array('name'=>'Kate','age'=>'22'));
```